# I want to change ContentViews environment object based on Condition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
@main
struct TSUDateApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage(CurrentUserDefaults.userID) var currentUserID: String?
    
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                if currentUserID != nil {
                    ContentView().environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
                        .environmentObject(MessageListVM(userID: currentUserID!))
                } else {
                    ContentView().environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change ContentViews environment object based on Condition, but it iterates only once and it is not updated if `currentUserID`changes, if i want to get logic I want i have to reload app than it is working. I tried `.onReceive` and `.onChange`, but it always fails.

I am changin `currentUserID` in `signOut()` function here

```
func signOut() {
    navigateToLoginView()
  
        let defaultsDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()
        defaultsDictionary.keys.forEach { key in
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    
    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you change `currentUserID`.

Comment: Please add code to your original question, not in a comment

Comment: okay, sorry I am new in posting questions

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `@AppStorage` does not refresh your view if something changes `UserDefaults` through any other method or even another `AppStorage` with the same key.

The most simple solution in this case would be to move the `currentUserID` to one of the ViewModels. As you are using `AuthViewModel` for both cases it seems that this is the appropriate container for this.

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @AppStorage("currentUserID") var currentUserID: String?
}

struct TSUDateApp: App {
    @StateObject private var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if let currentUserID = authViewModel.currentUserID{
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(authViewModel)
                    .environmentObject(MessageListVM(userID: currentUserID))
            } else {
                ContentView().environmentObject(authViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your`signOut` function would look like this:

```
func signOut() {
    navigateToLoginView()
  
    authViewModel.currentUserId = nil
    
    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
}
```

of course you would need to pull it from the environment first:

```
@EnvironmentObject private var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
```

---

Another approach would be to pass your `currentUserID` on as a `Binding` to your `ContentView`:

```
struct TSUDateApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("currentUserID") var currentUserID: String?
    
    var body: some View{
        if let currentUserID = currentUserID{
            ContentView(currentUserID: $currentUserID)
                .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
                .environmentObject(MessageListVM(userID: currentUserID))
        } else {
            ContentView(currentUserID: $currentUserID).environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

In `ContentView` create the Binding and manipulate it in `signOut`.

```
@Binding var currentUserID: String?

func signOut() {
    navigateToLoginView()

    currentUserId = nil

    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
}
```